# Should I change the title of this particular question?

Tags: discussion, editing

The answer to my question [Minimal subbases for the canonical topology on $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580277/how-does-one-prove-that-the-canonical-topology-on-mathbbr-does-not-have-a-m#580425) turned out to be the opposite of my presumed guess. Should I change the title to say, "How does one show that the canonical topology on $\mathbb{R}$ has a minimal subbase?" to avoid a misleading title?

Comment: _If_ you make any change to the title, I would recommend being a bit more neutral and using something like "Minimal subbases for the canonical topology on $\mathbb{R}$?"  (But then insert into your question your original guess that there is no minimal subbase.)